# Can I write a function to revalue levels of a factor?

Tags: r, function, plyr

I have a column 'lg_with_children' in my data frame that has 5 levels, 'Half and half', 'Mandarin', 'Shanghainese', 'Other', 'N/A', and 'Not important'. I want to condense the 5 levels down to just 2 levels, 'Shanghainese' and 'Other'.

In order to do this I used the revalue() function from the plyr package to successfully rename the levels. I used the code below and it worked fine.

```
data$lg_with_children <- revalue(data$lg_with_children,
                             c("Mandarin" = "Other"))
data$lg_with_children <- revalue(data$lg_with_children,
                             c("Half and half" = "Other"))
data$lg_with_children <- revalue(data$lg_with_children,
                             c("N/A" = "Other"))
data$lg_with_children <- revalue(data$lg_with_children,
                             c("Not important" = "Other"))
```

To condense the code a little I went back data before I revalued the levels and attempted to write a function. I tried the following after doing research on how to write your own functions (I'm rather new at this).

```
revalue_factor_levels <- function(df, col, source, target) {df$col <- revalue(df$col, c("source" = "target"))}
```

I intentionally left the df, col, source, and target generic because I need to revalue some other columns in the same way.

Next, I tried to run the code filling in the args and get this message:

[warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Squ5.jpg)

I am not quite sure what the problem is. I tried the following adjustment to code and still nothing.

```
revalue_factor_levels <- function(df, col, source, target) {df$col <- revalue(df$col, c(source = target))}
```

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `df[[col]] <- … df[[col]] ...` should do what you're want. At the moment, using the `$` operator you're referring to a column literally called "col"

Comment: revalue_factor_levels <- function(df, col, source, target) {df[[col]] <- revalue(df[[col]], c(source = target))}                                                                                                                                      I tried it and now it says object 'lg_with_children' not found

Comment: You need to pass a string `"lg_with_children"` as the `col` argument. See my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* write your function to recode the levels - the easiest way to do that is probably to change the levels directly with `levels(fac) <- list(new_lvl1 = c(old_lvl1, old_lvl2), new_lvl2 = c(old_lvl3, old_lvl4))`

But there are already several functions that do it out of the box. I typically use the `forcats` package to manipulate factors.

Check out `fct_recode` from the `forcats` package. [Link to doc](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_recode.html).

There are also other functions that could help you - check out the comments below.

Now, as to why your code isn't working:

- `df$col` looks for a column literally named `col`. The workaround is to do `df[[col]]` instead.
- Don't forget to return `df` at the end of your function
- `c(source = target)` will create a vector with one element named `"source"`, regardless of what happens to be in the variable `source`.
  The solution is to create the vector `c(source = target)` in 2 steps.

```
revalue_factor_levels <- function(df, col, source, target) {
  to_rename <- target
  names(to_rename) <- source
  df[[col]] <- revalue(df[[col]], to_rename)
  df
}
```

Returning the df means the syntax is:

```
data <- revalue_factor_levels(data, "lg_with_children", "Mandarin", "Other")
```

I like functions that take the data as the first argument and return the modified data because they are pipeable.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  revalue_factor_levels("lg_with_children", "Mandarin", "Other") %>%
  revalue_factor_levels("lg_with_children", "Half and half", "Other") %>%
  revalue_factor_levels("lg_with_children", "N/A", "Other")
```

Still, using `forcats` is easier and less prone to breaking on edge cases.

Edit:

There is nothing preventing you from both using `forcats` and creating your custom function. For example, this is closer to what you want to achieve:

```
revalue_factor_levels <- function(df, col, ref_level) {
  df[[col]] <- forcats::fct_others(df[[col]], keep = ref_level)
  df
}

# Will keep Shanghaisese and revalue other levels to "Other". 
data <- revalue_factor_levels(data, "lg_with_children", "Shanghainese")
```

Comment: To add to that, `fct_lump` or `fct_other` might do what OP wants in one step. [Link](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html)

Comment: That did work, thanks. The reason I was looking to create a generic function that takes df, col, source, and target arguments is because the data set I'm working with contains multiple columns that need to undergo a similar process of changing 4-5 levels to just 2, 'Lvl 1' and 'Other'. I thought maybe a generic function would be the best way to do, but it looks like there are maybe some better solutions based on the responses here.

Comment: @p.habermann then it sounds like your function should take only 3 arguments: df, col and ref_level, where ref_level is the level you want to keep ("Shanghainese" in your example). The code should then handle the logic that turns all other levels into "Others". Right now you have a thin wrapper around `revalue` which is not really useful. I suggest increasing the scope of your function. Remember you can get all levels of your factor with `levels(df[[col]])`.

Comment: @p.habermanm Note: There is nothing preventing you from both using `forcats` _and_ creating your custom function. See my edit!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with thanks to help from the community.

```
revalue_factor_levels <- function(df, col, ref_level) {
  df[[col]] <- fct_other(df[[col]], keep = ref_level)
  df
}

data <- revalue_factor_levels(data, "lg_with_children", "Shanghainese")
```